# How to add values of a thread only with others that are the same thread

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

so my question here is, say I have 6 threads, and I am running a program 2 times in a loop. I will have the same thread running the program twice for each thread. e.g.

Thread 1 : Value1

Thread 1 : Value2

Thread 1 : Value1

Thread 1 : Value2

....

Thread 6 : Value1

Thread 6 : Value2

Thread 6 : Value1

Thread 6 : Value2

How am I able to add all the 'Value1's from both Thread 1's together to store in an array that is the length of the number of threads (6). And then so forth up to Thread 6 Value1's get added to the other Thread 6 Value1 and stored in the last index of the array.

Comment: am i missing something or do you want join? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--

Comment: Sounds like you want to store values in that specific thread?  You can use `ThreadLocal` for that.